# iOS: Setting variables on several custom view objects

Tags: ios, variables, uiview

Okay, so I'm creating X number of a custom UIView, that I've created in IB...
I create them in a grid-like formation and need to set their individual properties based on a response from a web service call...

The part I'm having trouble with is how to iterate through the different UIViews and set the variables...

I'm pretty sure the solution is really simple, but I've been staring blindly at this for some time now...

It's the part after:

```
            if([theStatus.groupName isEqualToString:groupEntry.groupNameLabel.text])
            {
```

Here is the entire method:

```
- (void)receivedGroups
{
    int rows, columns;

    if([groupConnection.groupsArray count] <= 4)
    {
        rows = 1;
        columns = [groupConnection.groupsArray count];
    } else if([groupConnection.groupsArray count] >= 5 && [groupConnection.groupsArray count] <= 8)
    {
        rows = 2;
        columns = ([groupConnection.groupsArray count] + 1 )/ 2;
    } else
    {
        rows = 3;
        columns = ([groupConnection.groupsArray count] + 2 )/ 3;
    }

    int number = 0;

    for(int j=1; j < columns+1; j++)
    {
        for(int k=0; k < rows; k++)
        {
            // Only create the number of groups that match the number of entries in our array
            if(number < [groupConnection.groupsArray count])
            {
                // Create an instance of the group view
                GroupEntry *groupEntry = [[GroupEntry alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230*j, 250*k, 180, 233)];

                // Add it to the view
                [self.view addSubview:groupEntry];

                // Get the group
                GetGroupsActive *theGroups = [groupConnection.groupsArray objectAtIndex:number];

                groupEntry.groupNameLabel.text = theGroups.groupName;

                for(int i=0; i<[statusConnection.statusArray count]; i++)
                {                        
                    CurrentStatus *theStatus = [statusConnection.statusArray objectAtIndex:i];

                    if([theStatus.groupName isEqualToString:groupEntry.groupNameLabel.text])
                    {
                        //allChildren++;

                        switch(theStatus.currentStatus)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                //childrenSick++;
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                //childrenVacation++;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                //childrenPresent++;
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                //childrenOut++;
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                //childrenTour++;
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;

                        }
                    }
                }

                NSString *allLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", allChildren];
                NSString *sickLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", childrenSick];
                NSString *vacationLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", childrenVacation];
                NSString *presentLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", childrenPresent];
                NSString *outLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", childrenOut];
                NSString *tripLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", childrenTour];

                groupEntry.sickLabelNumber.text = sickLabelText;
                groupEntry.presentLabelNumber.text = presentLabelText;
                groupEntry.numberLabelNumber.text = allLabelText;
                groupEntry.tripLabelNumber.text = tripLabelText;
                groupEntry.outLabelNumber.text = outLabelText;
                groupEntry.vacationLabelNumber.text = vacationLabelText;

                // Create the buttons to handle button press
                UIButton *childButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

                childButton.frame = CGRectMake(230*j, 250*k, 180, 233);

                // Set an identity tag, so we can recognize it during button press
                childButton.tag = theGroups.ID;

                // When EventTouchUpInside, send an action to groupSelected:
                [childButton addTarget:self action:@selector(groupSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                // Add it to the view
                [self.view addSubview:childButton];
            }

            number++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you added all the views in a parent view. You can get all the subviews using,

```
NSAarry *subviews = [base subviews];
for(UIView *subview in subviews)
{
subview.property = yourVaule;
}
```

You can differentiate between subviews using its tag or another property.

Comment: I'm trying with `NSArray *subviews = [self.view subviews];
                for(GroupEntry *subview in subviews)
                {
                }` but it keeps crashing with Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton sickLabelNumber]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18bbb0'

Comment: your sub view has  method "sickLabelNumber" is it?.

Comment: Yeah, my subview has a label called sickLabelNumber

Comment: Ok.In your base view contains  button also. So you will have to make sure that you assign property to your view not buttons. you can do by checking [subview iskindClass:[UIView class]] .